# How to store c# list in NSUserDefaults

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to store a list contain a DateTime value and a String value for each element in NSUserDefaults.

```
var reminderList = new List<doubleVariableDateAndName>();
        NSDate dateNS = dateSet.Date;
        DateTime dateDT = ((DateTime)dateSet.Date).ToLocalTime();

        reminderList.Add(new doubleVariableDateAndName() { Name = nameSet.Text, DueDay = dateDT});
```

If it helps, you can ignore line 2 and 3 of the code and the list I want to store in NSUserDefaults in reminderList.

```
public NSUserDefaults dataBase = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;

    public class doubleVariableDateAndName
    {
        public string Name;
        public DateTime DueDay;
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you want to store `reminderList`  in UserDefaults

Comment: you could serialize your list before you store it. So then you would be storing it as a string. And then deserialize it when you go and pull it from the user defaults.

Answer (score 2):

I have not come across a way to store an object in NSUserDefaults. However i serialize and deserialize my object, you could do the same with your list.

So i have an Account object. Which i serialize to a string and then store in the NSUserDefaults like below

```
public void SaveAccount(Account account)
{
    var stringAccount = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(account);
    NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(stringAccount,AccountIdentifier);
}
```

And then to get the object back i deserialize it and return it.

```
public Account GetAccount()
{
   var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;
   var stringAccount = userDefaults.StringForKey(AccountIdentifier);
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringAccount))
   {
      var account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.Account>(stringAccount);
      return account;
   }

   return null;
}
```

I used Newtonsoft.Json to handle the serialization and deserialization. You can read up on it [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) if you do not use it already.

So for your list to serialize you would do something like

```
public void SaveList(List<doubleVariableDateAndName> reminderList)
{
    var serializedContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reminderList);
    NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(serializedContent ,"yourUniqueIdentifier");
}
```

And then to get your list back from the store you could use

```
public List<doubleVariableDateAndName> GetReminderList()
{
   var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;
   var serializedContent = userDefaults.StringForKey("yourUniqueIdentifier");
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(serializedContent ))
   {
      var reminderList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<doubleVariableDateAndName>>(serializedContent);
      return reminderList;
   }

   return null;
}
```

Reformat the functions to whatever works best for you, but this will allow you to store your list in the NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Where you have var serializedContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reminderList); comes up with an error saying that type 'Object' is not defined in an assembly.

Comment: @ByronBanzhaf If you have added newtonsoft.json nuget package to your project it should just work out of the box. If you edit your question and add the stack trace to the bottom i will try and help you sort it. Additionally you class definition for your doubleVariableDateAndName object would help too. Is it a build error or a run time error?

Comment: Sorry if i'm seeming kinda dumb but there doesn't seem to be anything in the call stack. I have updated the post with the class I am calling and check that newtonsoft .json is referenced.

Comment: @ByronBanzhaf Not at all we all have to start somewhere. Okay so lets think your writing a IOS app using xamarin. So you have one solution with a IOS app project. Do you have a project that contains shared code? For example with xamarin you would usually have a core project that contains your shared logic, similar to the diagram show here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/code-sharing , your solutions structure may require your packages to be referenced in each project you see

Comment: okay if that is the case you might just need to add a reference to this https://www.nuget.org/packages/NETStandard.Library.NETFramework/2.0.0-preview1-25305-02 so check if you already have a reference or not and if not try adding it as a nuget package and see if that helps. It sounds like the latest version of newtonsoft may require this package to be referenced

Comment: I have installed NetStandard.library howerver I can't seem to see any references to it.